# Share VPN connection (over internal Wi-Fi ) to USB Wi-Fi adapter (set up as access point)

Tags: network, wifi, vpn

I'm connecting to Wi-Fi via my MacBook's internal Wi-Fi adapter. Then connect to my VPN.

I want to share this VPN connection over USB Wi-Fi adapter (I'm using Archer T2U)

- First of all, I am not able to configure Archer T2U as access point at all. The software driver doesn't have an option like that. Though I did set it up as access point on Windows.
- I could connect to Wi-Fi via USB Wi-Fi adapter. Then when I connect to VPN, it's also connected. But when I try to share the VPN connection through internal Wi-Fi, it's not working. VPN drops connection and because VPN is dropped, Wi-Fi couldn't find anything to share.

Is there any way to set up USB Wi-Fi adapter as access point other than its software (via command-line or anything else)?

Why does VPN connection drops when I try to share it over internal Wi-Fi? It would work if the connection stays I think.